# Magento 2 extension downloads but does appear in enabled/disabled module list

Tags: magento2, extensions

I've just downloaded an extension via SSH like this...

```
composer require magefan/module-blog
```

It tells me it has downloaded 100% successfully and refreshes the command line.

I then got to check that the extension is available to install like this...

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

But the module is nowhere on the list, either disabled or enabled.

I've tried this with three extensions now, and it is the same every time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you see it when you type in `composer info`???

Comment: run setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy then check.

Comment: I have done all those, but still nothing in the enabled or disable module lists.

Comment: Is it showing on your vendor folder?

Comment: No it isn't, no changes to that folder today.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the vendor folder, or app/code (typically composer modules go in the vendor folder, but it can depend on the composer file), then it likely hasn't installed.

Recommended to try installing it again. You can also try clearing composer cache in case of a corrupt download `composer clearcache`, and trying again.